# Popup exit animation tweaked because of css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, popup

Sup, 
I'm working on a shopify page and have created a popup slider which shows the sizing table etc.  
So basically because of the css `top: 0; bottom: 0` the animation closes but going to the top right. 
I want the animation to be the same like the entry animation.
Basically I can't control the exit animation to just slide out to the right without it going to the top.

See JSFiddle for the full code and reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/Komplexe/zcnwyegq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a much simpler way to do this just by using CSS
https://jsfiddle.net/3owkLsag/5/

```
.sizing-table-container {
  transition: 333ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 30px));
}

.opened .sizing-table-container {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

All you need to do is switch the `.open` class and use it to hide/show the menu behind the edge of the screen.

```
    $(".close-call").click(function () {
      
      $("body").toggleClass("opened");
      
    });
```